# Keep getting ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to fix this query for a while now and I keep getting error:

> ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Any tips on what I could be doing wrong.

```
SELECT ACTIVITY_APPROVAL_DATE, COUNT(*)AS ACTIVITY_COUNT 
FROM ACTIVITY 
WHERE ACTIVITY_APPROVAL_DATE = CURRENT_DATE() 
GROUP BY ACTIVITY_APPROVAL_DATE;
```

Comment: I guess no empty parameter brackets after current_Date method in oracle sql you should use.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions051.htm#SQLRF00628

Comment: @JamesFlower . . . Do you really need the timezone component?

Answer (score 3):

Remove `()` from `CURRENT_DATE()`

```
SELECT ACTIVITY_APPROVAL_DATE, COUNT(*)AS ACTIVITY_COUNT 
FROM ACTIVITY 
WHERE ACTIVITY_APPROVAL_DATE = CURRENT_DATE
GROUP BY ACTIVITY_APPROVAL_DATE;
```

Answer (score 2):

If this is Oracle, then use `sysdate`:

```
SELECT ACTIVITY_APPROVAL_DATE, COUNT(*)AS ACTIVITY_COUNT 
FROM ACTIVITY 
WHERE ACTIVITY_APPROVAL_DATE = TRUNC(sysdate) 
GROUP BY ACTIVITY_APPROVAL_DATE;
```

If `ACTIVITY_APPROVAL_DATE` has a time component, then you need to take that into account:

```
SELECT ACTIVITY_APPROVAL_DATE, COUNT(*)AS ACTIVITY_COUNT 
FROM ACTIVITY 
WHERE ACTIVITY_APPROVAL_DATE >= TRUNC(sysdate) AND
      ACTIVITY_APPROVAL_DATE < TRUNC(sysdate + 1)
GROUP BY ACTIVITY_APPROVAL_DATE;
```

Comment: You can use `current_date` in Oracle (which I'm pretty sure you know!); but which to use depends on whether the OP meant the system time or the session time, if they're in different time zones. The trunc/range changes apply either way of course.