# what does this error means and how to fix it

Tags: sql, oracle

```
select round(long_w,4) 
  from station  
 where lat_n < 137.2345 
 order by lat_n desc 
 limit 1;
```

this query give

> - ERROR at line 1:  ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

fix this error

Comment: ORA-00933 is a general message indicating our SQL statements contain at least one syntax error. The solution is to consult the Oracle SQL Reference. There's plenty of guidance on valid syntax. For instance, [here are examples of row limiting queries](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10002.htm#BABEAACC). It's worth bookmarking [the docs site for future reference](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/index.htm).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8940471/sql-error-ora-00933-sql-command-not-properly-ended)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Keep getting ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35798347/keep-getting-ora-00933-sql-command-not-properly-ended)

Answer (score 1):

Oracle does not support `limit` and you are getting an Oracle error.  You can instead use:

```
select round(long_w, 4)
from station
where lat_n < 137.2345
order by lat_n desc 
fetch first 1 row only;
```

`fetch` was introduced in Oracle 12.  You can also use the `keep` syntax:

```
select max(round(long_w, 4)) keep (dense_rank first order by lat_n desc)
from station
where lat_n < 137.2345;
```